# Transform text in python

Tags: python, linux, sed

I have data in the following format:

```
   This is line1 <line 1>.
   This is line2 <http://<line2> .
   This is line3 <http://<>line3>.
   This is line4 <line4> .
```

I want to transform this data into the following format:

```
   #@ <line 1>
   This is line1.
   #@ <http://<line2>
   This is line2.
   #@ <<http://<>line3> 
   This is line3. 
   #@ <line4>
   This is line4.
```

I tried in python by splitting at < but it does not solve my purpose as '<' and '>' are present within strings themselves. 
Is there any way in python or linux(sed, etc) by which I may achieve the above given transformation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split only at the first `<`:

```
with open('foo.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        a, b = line.split('<', 1)
        b = '#@ <' + b.rstrip('. \n')
        print b
        print a.rstrip() + '.'
```

**Output:**

```
#@ <line 1>
This is line1.
#@ <http://<line2>
This is line2.
#@ <http://<>line3>
This is line3.
#@ <line4>
This is line4.
```

Comment: I have changed the input of question. My apologies I think that the input is somewhat misleading

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\(<line[0-9]\{1,\}>\)./#@ \2\
\1./' YourFile
```

Comment: It is not necessary that my line begins with "This is". Sorry for my mistake in the question..i have modified it.